# Is it possible to put strings at the yAxis in MUI X-Charts?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mui-x-charts

I am using MUI X-Charts BarChart and i could style mostly desired props, but my yAxis is going from 0 to 2 and I would like to display them as "Bad" (0), "Regular" (1) and "Good" (2). Is it possible to do that?

Using @mui/x-charts 7.0.0